# Custom menu not getting displayed on odoo portal view

Tags: python, odoo

I want to display the custom menu on the odoo portal view.
XML File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
      <template id="portal_my_home_loan" name="Partner Loan"
        customize_show="True" inherit_id="portal.portal_my_home">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_portal_docs')]" position="inside">
          <t t-call="portal.portal_docs_entry">
            <t t-set="title">Partner Loan</t>
            <t t-set="url" t-value="'/my/loan'" />
            <!-- <t t-set="placeholder_count" t-value="'loan_count'" /> -->
          </t>
        </xpath>
      </template>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

python file:

```py
from odoo.addons.portal.controllers.portal import CustomerPortal

class PortalAccount(CustomerPortal):
   def _prepare_home_portal_values(self, counters):
       values = super()._prepare_home_portal_values(counters)
       values['loan_count'] = 1
       return values
```

Have added `portal` to depends in the manifest file as well as template.xml to the manifest file. Still can't see the menu on my portal view of the user.
Any idea where I could go have gone wrong?

Comment: which odoo version you are using?

Comment: its odoo version 16.0